# Mac ;9D and ;9C from alt-left and alt-right

Tags: mac, terminal

I am very used to using alt-left to go to the word before (if you use vim, that's 'b') and alt-right to go to the beginning of the next word.

On Mac terminal however (iterm and iterm2), I am getting ;9D and ;9C respectively. I can use fn+left to go the beginning of the line but I still find that really inconvenient.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using the `bash` shell, add the following to your `~/.inputrc`:

```
"\e[1;9C": forward-word
"\e[1;9D": backward-word
```

Press <kbd>Ctrl-X</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd> or restart the shell to apply changes.

---

*Note:* Part of the escape sequences above, specifically the `1`, I had to guess based on what Xterm uses.

Comment: Thx! This works! Thought Ctrl-x Ctrl-e doesn't really do anything

Answer (score 0):

In Terminal in OS X Lion, this works as expected. Otherwise, you might try M-b and M-f (the Meta key might be option or escape depending on your terminal program).

Answer (score 0):

You can map <kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>Left/Right Arrow</kbd> to <kbd>Esc</kbd>-<kbd>b/f</kbd> in Terminal preferences. These will work with bash (the default shell) and any program with Emacs-compatible key bindings.

> Terminal > Preferences > Settings > [profile] > Keyboard

Click the plus button to add a new mapping:

Key: cursor left
Modifier: option
Action: send string to shell
String: \033b

(Type the Esc key to enter "\033".)

Then add another mapping for "cursor right" to "\033f".

As of Mac OS X Lion 10.7, Terminal's default keyboard map includes these two entries so there's no need to do this.