# Create keyboard bindings for go back word and go forward word in iTerm using config file?

Tags: iterm, inputrc

I have tried adding the following to my `~/.inputrc` but it doesn't work

```
"\e[1;9D": backward-word
"\e[1;9C": forward-word
```

What more do I need to do?

Comment: What key are you pressing? If you haven't already, take a look at how MacOS handles the Meta key: https://superuser.com/questions/649960/option-key-does-not-work-as-meta-in-tmux

Comment: I'm pressing alt-back arrow and alt-forward arrow. I have also tried setting alt as meta or esc+. That didn't work either.

Comment: If you don't include the lines in your `~/.inputrc`, are you seeing the characters printed in your terminal? Did you add those lines due to [this question?](https://superuser.com/questions/324689/mac-9d-and-9c-from-alt-left-and-alt-right)

Comment: Also, you can see [this related question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/136928/using-alt-cmd-right-left-arrow-in-iterm) on Ask Different.